# Why is CakePHP inserting a space before my xml layout?

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, kml

I am having a really frustrating problem in CakePHP where a space keeps coming up at the beginning of my KML file layout which causes Google Earth to reject the KML file!

```
<?php header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=area.kml");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml kml; charset=utf8");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
 ?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <?php echo $content_for_layout ?>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

for the output I get

```
" <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"
```

ect ect
please help!

Comment: Are you sure, that no characters are sent before the header? Like trailing whitespace in controller classes etc.? Have you confirmed that e.g. by trying to send a "Location: http://www.example.com/" (redirect) header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if you're including a php file that has a space after the closing `?>`. For this reason, it is generally recommended that you don't include that tag (except, e.g., in a view, where you're `echo`ing a variable and other content follows).

Comment: after 2 hours of debugging ... space in app_model

Comment: Some here, in my captcha component, space before php tag. I edited the init function in ComponentsCollection to find where it was.

Answer (score 1):

It's the c/r after the ?> tag and before the <kml tag.  Put them together and it should be better.  Like this...

?><kml

Answer (score 0):

use `ob_clean ();` to clean the white space